# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference in Android

Tags: android

I'm creating a cardview inside tablayout but i'm getting an error in adapter class.Below is the logcat,adapter class and Demo java class.I tried to find out in google as well as in stackover flow but unfortunately i unable to find the solution.Kindly help me of this error because i'm a beginner in android.

> logcat

```
2019-04-06 22:14:37.450 32524-32524/com.example.counter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.counter, PID: 32524
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:229)
        at com.example.counter.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:43)
        at com.example.counter.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:28)
```

> Adapter class

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ProductViewHolder>  { // error getting

        private Context context;
        private List<Demo> demos;



        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Demo> demos) {
            this.context = context;
            this.demos = demos;
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {    // error getting 
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, viewGroup, false);
                return new ProductViewHolder(view);

        }
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder productViewHolder, int i) {
        final Demo demo = demos.get(i);
        productViewHolder.textview1.setText(demo.getTextview1());
        productViewHolder.textview2.setText(demo.getTextview2());
        productViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tv1 = demo.getTextview1();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text_1", tv1);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity)context).finish();
                Animatoo.animateSlideRight(context);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return demos.size();
    }
    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textview1, textview2;
        CardView cardView;
        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textview1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            textview2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        }
    }
}
```

> Demo Class

```
public class Demo {
    private String textview1,textview2;

    public Demo(String textview1, String textview2) {
        this.textview1 = textview1;
        this.textview2 = textview2;
    }

    public String getTextview1() {
        return textview1;
    }

    public String getTextview2() {
        return textview2;
    }


}
```

> Frag1.Java

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    Context c;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_1,container,false);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
        ArrayList<Demo> demoList=new ArrayList<>();
        demoList.add(new Demo("A","B"));
        adapter=new MyAdapter(c,demoList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What context do use pass as a constructor parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @S-Sh  The context is for to inflate the xml file.

Comment: @mohammednabil, I mean, how do you create `MyAdapter` instance?

Comment: @S-Sh I forgot to mention that i also created a java class named as Demo which contain a list,then in adapter class i create a Adapter constructor which i pass two parameter context and that java Demo class name

Comment: @mohammednabil, please, post code with appropriate `new MyAdapter(...)` statement. It's important to know what value you pass as a context

Comment: @S-Sh  I have updated the question as well as the code,kindly check above

Comment: @mohammednabil, how do you **create** `MyAdapter` instance? Is it in activity/fragment?  Post the code, please.

Comment: @S-Sh It is in fragment and also i have added the Fragment code at above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Context` in Frag1 class is obviously null. You should pass `getActivity()` instead of `Context` in Frag1 class.

```
adapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(),demoList);
```

Comment: This answer is rigth but you should explain that the context originally used is null because is not instantiated and why your context is suitable